# Confusion on how event loop works in Node.js

Tags: node.js

I was learning event loop in Node.js and faced some confusion on how exactly it works behind the scenes. Yeah, I certainly watched famous explanation of how event loop works here https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ&list=LLhF0R_fY9ZAKaJN1bVTrOdg&index=1637 but still face some problems with that concept in Node.js. The first question is "Is it true that Event loop in Node.js will ONLY be run only if there is at least ONE event handler registered?" that is, say we have this code: `console.log('Hey', 1000)` then will event loop be executed when that code is called?

The second question is "Is it true that Event loop itself executes callback functions or does it pass callback functions to call stack to be called then?"

Comment: The event loop is *constantly* executing. It's a loop. It's essentially `whilte(true) { task = takeFromQueue(); if (task) run(task); }`. When you have executable code, the loop isn't *called* - it's *running* and picking up the next thing to execute. As for callback functions, depends on how they are used. If they are used synchronously, then they'd be executed within the same loop. If they are part of some async task, then they'd be executed when that that is done.

Comment: @VLAZ, hey)) thank you for your kind comments, sorry some questions. Firstly, I read somewhere that Event loop is ONLY executed if there is at least one event listener and if there is no listener at all, event loop is not called. Right? Secondly, if callback function is called synchronously, is it called by call stack and not event loop. Right? lastly, imagine we use asynchronous writeFile function. So, what will happen when JS engine encounters writeFile? Will writeFile be sent to Node API to not block main thread and its callback will then be called by event loop and not by call stack?

Comment: If there are no event listeners or tasks in the queue remaining, the event loop (and thus your program) will exit. Synchronous callbacks will be executed in the same context as the function that calls them. Asynchronous functions will put a new item in the queue (the async operation) and immediately return a Promise that represents that future result.

Comment: @Sirko, two questions, does event loop in Node.js work differently compared to event loop in browser? Lastly, sorry this thing confuses me a lot, pls can you briefly depict how asynchronous readFile function with its callback is executed behind the scenes. Pls it would be really kind of you))

Comment: @Sirko, because here is what I think will happen when readFile or writeFile is used. Pls I just need your confirmation. So,when js engine sees readFile or writeFile then it will be sent to Node API because readFile(or writeFile) is asynchronous. So, readFile will do its reading job in Node Api without blocking main thread and once it is done then the data is passed to its callback function. And that callback function is executed by event loop. Right? gosh so hard to be beginner :D

Comment: From a conceptual point of view, the event loop in browsers and NodeJS is the same. However, in the browser context you have access to the DOM and other events might be assigned (also automatically) through the browser environment.

Comment: Regarding the nitty-gritty details of NodeJS' internal behavior I'm not really sure. I would imagine when you call `readFile()` in JS you basically do two things: Hand off the actuall execution to the respective C-library and setting up an event when this is finished. When that event is triggered it will receive the payload and execute the callback again in the NodeJS context aka the event loop.

Comment: @Sirko, hmmm, I thought event loop is like a middleman that passes callback function into call stack as it is in browser event loop but as you said, event loop actually runs the code instead of passing callback into call stack